# Polymer 1: Prevent iron-pages/app-route from attaching all pages at load

Tags: performance, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer 1 `app-route` with `iron-pages` like in the examples and `starter-kit`. I find that all elements are attached on page load. This causes quite abit of slow down at start. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I had a look at the code of `iron-pages` and have to conclude that there is no inherent way of avoiding that. `iron-pages` simply loads the content and then proceeds to hide/unhide each element using `iron-resizable-behavior`.

The work-arounds I can think of are clunky: you could wrap each element in a `dom-if` template or you could limit the `dom-if`'s to those elements that slow down the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polymer Staret Kit v2 which is based on the the [PRPL pattern](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/server) supports lazy loading of routes. 
You can use `importHref` together with an observer on a route change to lazy load pages for `iron-pages`. See [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/src/my-app.html#L130) for code sample

Comment: This made my day! I've got one view that is super processor heavy and slows everything down. Is it possible to un-load this view whenever I leave it? For example, going from main.html to heavy.html it will load. Then going back to main.html the heavy stuff gets released/unloaded

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [iron-lazy-ages](https://github.com/TimvdLippe/iron-lazy-pages), which loads a page when you change your `route` to its endpoint.